# Returning a lambda with captures from a function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

In C++11 one can write lambdas with captures (and that's awesome!)

```
auto myfunc = [&] (int i) {return i + j;}; // j being somewhere in the lambda's context
```

That is awesome! However, it would be very nice if one could return such a lambda from a function, or even from another lambda. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Yup, its possible. There are plenty of examples: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=c%2b%2b%20nested%20lambdas

Comment: Closures in C++ don't extend the lifetime of variables captured by reference. That's different from what you see in other languages. [I blogged on this once](http://kos.gd/2013/01/closures-the-cute-pets-that-bite/)

Comment: @Kos C++ speaks of "capture", not "closure".  I suspect that this is the reason; there is no closure, in the classical sense.

Comment: @JamesKanze C++11 [expr.prim.lambda]/2: "The evaluation of a *lambda-expression* results in a prvalue temporary (12.2). This temporary is called the *closure object*." C++11 speaks of "closure," but as with so many terms stolen from functional programming we use it to mean something else ;)

Comment: @Casey It's a "closure object", not a "closure":-).  Seriously, there was never any question of C++ implementing true closure; that would require garbage collection of some sort, and the possibility that local variables weren't on the stack.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, you'd have to wrap it in a function object of known type to return it from a function:

```
std::function<int(int)> get_lambda() {
    return [&] (int i) {return i + j;};
}
```

In C++14, you can use `auto` to return the lambda type itself:

```
auto get_lambda() {
    return [&] (int i) {return i + j;};
}
```

In either dialect, you could return it from a lambda:

```
auto get_lambda = [&] {return [&] (int i) {return i + j;};};
```

Note that you wouldn't want to return this particular lambda, since it captures a reference to a local variable `j`. The variable will be destroyed, leaving the reference invalid, when the function returns.

Comment: std::function<int(int)> get_lambda() {
    int j=3;
    return [&] (int i) {return i + j;};
}

int main()
{
    cout<<get_lambda()(4)<<endl;
}

It just prints out some random value! Prints 32771... what's going on in here??

Comment: @MatteoMonti: As I mentioned in the last sentence, you're capturing a reference to a local variable, which has been destroyed by the time you call the lambda. Don't do that.

Comment: @MatteoMonti: Note that your lambda is capturing `j` by reference, which is only in scope during the call to `get_lambda()`.

Comment: Oh gosh. What a fool. That was obvious. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, but what if I wanted it to work with some temporary variable? Say that I want a function to which I can give an int j and it returns a lambda that provided with an int i returns i + j. How could I do this? j will always be destroyed at the end of the function that creates the lambda, right? How can I work around this?

Comment: @MatteoMonti: Capture by value. Change `[&]` to either `[=]` or `[j]`

Comment: That's sweet. Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can [return](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/917812a9d704e13b) a lambda with captures. Since c++14 introduced automatic return types this is particularly easy.

Here's an example of how to create a function that will apply a binary operator (multiplication here, but it's a template parameter so you can give it anything) with one argument fixed during creation and the second provided during calling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename F, typename T>
auto opby(F func, T arg)
{
    return [=](auto val) {
        return func(val, arg); 
    };
}


int main()
{
 auto mu = opby(std::multiplies<int>(), 2); 
 std::cout << mu(3) << std::endl;
}
```

it prints 6. The returned lambda had **captured by value its enclosing scope** so a function is created that will multiply by two any argument you'll give it.

The only caveat is when [**capturing by reference**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea7463536f4a1d45) : you have to ensure that the closure won't transcend the lifetime of captured objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide a simple example of the accepted answer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto get_lambda(int j) {
    //capture by value here
    return [=](int i) {return i + j; };
}

int main() {
    auto f = get_lambda(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cout << f(i) << endl;
    }
}
```

This looks just like the closure in JavaScript and Python. Horraayy!